# API de SMS integrada com PHP

Tags: php, api, sms

Possuo um formulário de agendamento de visitas, quando o usuário faz seu agendamento e confirma é disparado um e-mail para o mesmo com informações do agendamento. Gostaria de saber se alguém já integrou uma API de SMS com PHP.

Exemplo:

Minha API de envio utiliza a seguinte URL para mandar o SMS

http://sitedeenvio.com.br/api/v1/send?cpf=XXXXXXXXXXX&password=XXXXXXXXXX&type=short&numbers=55DDDCELULAR&messages=Hello World

Como que faço para incluir essa API logo que dispara o e-mail já de confirmação para o usuario sobre o agendamento.

Parte do código do form de entrada dos dados

```
            <div id="wizard-frame-3" class="wizard-frame" style="display:none;">
                <div class="frame-container">

                    <h3 class="frame-title"><?php echo $this->lang->line('step_three_title'); ?></h3>

                    <div class="frame-content row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="first-name" class="control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('first_name'); ?> *</label>
                                <input type="text" id="first-name" class="required form-control" maxlength="100" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="last-name" class="control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('last_name'); ?> *</label>
                                <input type="text" id="last-name" class="required form-control" maxlength="250" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('email'); ?> *</label>
                                <input type="text" id="email" class="required form-control" maxlength="250" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="phone-number" class="control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('phone_number'); ?> *</label>
                                <input type="text" id="phone-number" class="required form-control" maxlength="60" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="address" class="control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('address'); ?></label>
                                <input type="text" id="address" class="form-control" maxlength="250" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="city" class="control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('city'); ?></label>
                                <input type="text" id="city" class="form-control" maxlength="120" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="zip-code" class="control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('zip_code'); ?></label>
                                <input type="text" id="zip-code" class="form-control" maxlength="120" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="notes" class="control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('notes'); ?></label>
                                <textarea id="notes" maxlength="500" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <em id="form-message" class="text-danger"><?php echo $this->lang->line('fields_are_required'); ?></em>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="command-buttons">
                    <button type="button" id="button-back-3" class="btn button-back btn-default"
                            data-step_index="3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
                        <?php echo $this->lang->line('back'); ?>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" id="button-next-3" class="btn button-next btn-primary"
                            data-step_index="3">
                        <?php echo $this->lang->line('next'); ?>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

            </div>

            <?php
                // ------------------------------------------------------
                // APPOINTMENT DATA CONFIRMATION
                // ------------------------------------------------------ ?>

            <div id="wizard-frame-4" class="wizard-frame" style="display:none;">
                <div class="frame-container">
                    <h3 class="frame-title"><?php echo $this->lang->line('step_four_title'); ?></h3>
                    <div class="frame-content row">
                        <div id="appointment-details" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>
                        <div id="customer-details" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php if ($this->settings_model->get_setting('require_captcha') === '1'): ?>
                    <div class="frame-content row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                            <h4 class="captcha-title">
                                CAPTCHA
                                <small class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></small>
                            </h4>
                            <img class="captcha-image" src="<?php echo site_url('captcha'); ?>">
                            <input class="captcha-text" type="text" value="" />
                            <span id="captcha-hint" class="help-block" style="opacity:0">&nbsp;</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="command-buttons">
                    <button type="button" id="button-back-4" class="btn button-back btn-default"
                            data-step_index="4">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
                        <?php echo $this->lang->line('back'); ?>
                    </button>
                    <form id="book-appointment-form" style="display:inline-block" method="post">
                        <button id="book-appointment-submit" type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                            <?php
                                echo (!$manage_mode) ? $this->lang->line('confirm')
                                        : $this->lang->line('update');
                            ?>
                        </button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_data" />
                    </form>


                </div>

            </div>
```

Arquivo de envio do email

```
<title>Appointment Details</title>



    <div id="content" style="padding: 10px 15px;">
        <h2>$email_title</h2>
        <p>$email_message</p>

        <h2>Appointment Details</h2>
        <table id="appointment-details">
            <tr>
                <td class="label" style="padding: 3px;font-weight: bold;">Service</td>
                <td style="padding: 3px;">$appointment_service</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label" style="padding: 3px;font-weight: bold;">Provider</td>
                <td style="padding: 3px;">$appointment_provider</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label" style="padding: 3px;font-weight: bold;">Start</td>
                <td style="padding: 3px;">$appointment_start_date</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label" style="padding: 3px;font-weight: bold;">End</td>
                <td style="padding: 3px;">$appointment_end_date</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <h2>Customer Details</h2>
        <table id="customer-details">
            <tr>
                <td class="label" style="padding: 3px;font-weight: bold;">Name</td>
                <td style="padding: 3px;">$customer_name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label" style="padding: 3px;font-weight: bold;">Email</td>
                <td style="padding: 3px;">$customer_email</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label" style="padding: 3px;font-weight: bold;">Phone</td>
                <td style="padding: 3px;">$customer_phone</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label" style="padding: 3px;font-weight: bold;">Address</td>
                <td style="padding: 3px;">$customer_address</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <h2>Appointment Link</h2>
        <a href="$appointment_link" style="width: 600px;">$appointment_link</a>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Alex tenho um sistema de sms integrado com e-mail, só fiquei com duvida vc quer que envia o sms após  o envio do e-mail?

Comment: Diego, eu tenho um formulário de agendamento que já funciona, logo que o usuario realiza um agendamento automaticamente já dispara para o email dele as informações do agendamento que ele fez OK?

Dai eu possuo um sistema de envio de SMS que tem uma API que dá para integrar nesse sistema de agendamento de visitas.

queria fazer com que logo que ele confirmasse o agendamento além de enviar o email de confirmação enviasse um sms para o numero da pessoa que ja foi cadastrado no formulario. conseguiu entender?

Comment: ok vou postar a resposta.

Comment: Diego se quiser, posto parte do meu código aqui.

Comment: coloque, que tento adaptar.

Comment: Atualizei o código na pergunta já, se precisar de mais algo eu pego aqui..

Comment: vc envial o e-mail com a function mail(); correto?

Comment: Isso , com mail();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Adaptei um código que tenho aqui, para tentar te auxiliar ##

vc informou que seu formulário e envio de email já esta funcionando. então não vou me atentar a isto:

```
//SEU CODIGO DE AGENDAMENTO.
//supondo que vc envia o sms depois da resposta do e-mail
$email = "email-destino@destino.com.br";
$assunto = "Assunto do e-mail";
$corpo = "Aqui escreve o teu contéudo.";
$cabecalho = "From: seu-email@remetente.com.br" . "\r\n" .
        "Reply-To:" . $email . "\r\n" .
        "X-mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

$assunto = '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($assunto) . '?=';

if (mail($email, $assunto, $corpo, $cabecalho)) { //se o email for enviado da TRUE e passa pelo if
 $msg = trim($corpo);// supondo ser a msm mensagem
    $url = "http://sitedeenvio.com.br/api/v1/send?cpf=XXXXXXXXXXX&password=XXXXXXXXXX&type=short&numbers=55DDDCELULAR&messages=$msg";
    $link = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($link, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($link, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($link, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $resposta = curl_exec($link); // resposta da sua plataforma de envio de sms
    var_dump($resposta); //resposta do envio do sms.
} else {
    echo 'não enviado!';
}
```

[referencia PHP mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Legal, vou incluir no meu codigo e fazer as alterações necessárias mas já me esclareceu muito.

Muito obrigado..